# What should I add to my appId in my configuration?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add and configure react-facebook (comments) into my website but there is not many sources about react facebook so i am interested

```
<FacebookProvider appId="123456789">
     <Comments href="https://facebook.com"/>
</FacebookProvider>
```

what should i add  instead of "123456789" (appId) and instead of href (Comment's prop) and do i need something else to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an app at https://developers.facebook.com/ and use its ID.

The `href` is up to you. It will be a URL on your site. If you want multiple comments sections, use separate URLs for each. For example, if you built a restaurant review website, you'd use something like `https://example.com/restaurants/bobs-burgers` for comments on Bob's Burgers, and `https://example.com/restaurants/mcdonalds` for the comments about McDonalds.

Comment: Yes, but you'll need the actual ID and name of a particular page, not the placeholders. You might also consider just using the ID, as changing the name would remove all the comments. The `href` is basically your comments section's unique identifier.

Comment: I just created ID and you are telling me to just leave href as it is? or `http://localhost:3000/:id/:name`. I am adding FB comment to my react app first time and i am bit confused

Comment: By the way i just added http://localhost:3000/:id/:name this to href and it works but problem is that if i post comment "Hey" to http://localhost:3000/123123123/Page1
it is shown to http://localhost:3000/123125453/Page2 too, and how can i fix it?

Comment: @iLiA Like I said, "you'll need the actual ID and name of a particular page, not the placeholders". Your `href` on `http://localhost:3000/123123123/Page1` should be  `http://localhost:3000/123123123/Page1` (or `http://localhost:3000/123123123` - as long as it's unique to that page).

Answer (score 1):

your own appId that you registered with facebook developer

please check [facebook developers official documentation website](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/)

> App ID When you register, we will generate a unique App ID for your
>   app. You will use this a lot, since it must be included when making
>   any calls to our APIs. All of our SDKs provide a way for you to easily
>   set this so it will automatically be included with any API calls.

Comment: can i add something like this to `href` ? `http://localhost:3000/:id/:name`